# How to filter/sample spans by tracestate header in the OTEL collector?

Tags: open-telemetry-collector

Is it possible to filter/sample spans by `tracestate` header?

For example, is the following configuration expected to work:

```
processors:
  filter/ottl:
    error_mode: ignore
    traces:
      span:
        - 'trace_state["key"] == "value"'
```

According to resources here:

- https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/processor/filterprocessor
- https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/blob/main/pkg/ottl/contexts/ottlspan/README.md

it should work, but I couldn't get it working.

Thanks in advance.